# Is Vagrant useful if you're developing alone?

Tags: vagrant

Some days ago I discovered Vagrant, and I found it very extremely interesting, especially for teams.

I'm really interested in learn how Vagrant works and how to use it in depth, but I don't know if it can be useful for projects where you work alone.

Comment: Did you find the answer below useful?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I completely forgot to accept it. Sorry and thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly use Vagrant when you are developing alone. Let's say you built a simple LAMP-stack application and you wanted to test under different workloads. You could create environments using Vagrant. Start up first environment and test against, say, 10K records. Stop this and start new environment using Vagrant and test against 10x workload etc.

If you are working on multiple projects, Vagrant can help you create environments for different projects that can help ease testing/QA. Check this http://www.slideshare.net/mjrsilva/vagrant-team-development-mande-easy slide-deck.

If you wanted to learn MySQL replication, for example, use Vagrant to fire up two environments with MySQL running and test out variety of replication scenarios.